# Complex MySQL Delete Query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Current Structure**

[image: SQL ERM Diagram]

As you can see Path can be referenced by multiple Tables and multiple records within those tables.

Points can also be referenced by two different tables.

**My Question**

1. I would like to delete a `PathType` however this gets complicated as
   a `Path` may be owned by more than one `PathType` so deleting the
   `Path` without checking how many references there are to it is out
   of the question.
2. Secondly, if this `Path`'s only reference is the `PathType` I'm
   trying to delete then I will want to delete this `Path` and any
   records in `PathPoints`.
3. Lastly, if there are no other references on `Point` from any other records then this will also need to be deleted but **only** if its not used by any other object.

**Attempts So Far**

`DELETE PathType1.*, Path.*, PathPoints.*, Point.* FROM PathType1,Path,PathPoints,Point WHERE PathType1.ID = 1 AND PathType1.PATH = Path.ID AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PathType1 WHERE PathType1.PATH = Path.ID) < 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PathType2 WHERE PathType2.PATH = Path.ID) = 0`

Obviously the above statement goes on but this isn't the right way about I don't think because if one fails then nothing is deleted...

I think that maybe it isn't possible to do what I'm attempting through one statement and I may have to iterate through each section and handle them based on the outcome. Not so efficient but I don't see any alternative at this time.

I hope this is clear. If you have any more questions or need any clarification then please do not hesitate to ask

Comment: `The italic words are the table names. Where there are foreign keys I have specified them.` Why don't you post the real DDL for the five tables. Much easier to read, IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser unsure of how to do this so created a quick EER diagram using MySQLWorkbench

Comment: First thing I would do is rewriting the (COUNT(*)) subqeries into `NOT EXISTS(...)` form. And add some whitespace...

Comment: You should NEVER use implicit syntax for anything. It is a SQL antipattern and is subject to errors like accidental crioss joins while having no advantages whatsoever. This is syntax replaced more tha 20 years ago. Time to comeinto the 21st century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is no way I would do this in a query like that even if the database allowed it which most will not. This is an unmaintanable mess.

The preferred method is to create a transaction, then delete from one table at a time starting with the bottommost child table. Then commit the transaction. And of course have error handling so the entire transaction is riolled back if one delete fails to maintain data integrity. If I intended to do this repeatedly, I would do it in a stored proc.

Comment: Thank you I already knew about transactions but for some reason I thought there may be a way as single statement or that it would be more efficient. Anyway thank you for pointing me in the right direction (new to this data handling stuff)